# Syntax error, unexpected ':' expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby

1. help me with this code T_T why it keep showing syntax error, unexpected ':' exepcting end-of-input database: {

   ```
   database: {
       total_car_price: 20000,
       stock_car_price: 20000,
       features: {
           rim: {
               '16' => 50,
               '15' => 30,
               '14' => 10
           },
           color: {
               'blue' => 0,
               'red'  => 0,
               'yellow' => 0
           },
           tint: {
               '100' => 80,
               '80' => 50,
               '50' => 0
           },
           seat: {
               'leather' => 500,
               'PVC' => 300
           }
       }
   }

   puts "Original price : #{database[:stock_car_price]}"

   database[:features].each do |feature, data|
       puts feature.upcase
       data.each do |option, extra_cost|
           puts "#{option} :: #{extra_cost}"
       end
       while true
           selection = gets.chomp
           if data.keys.include? selection #make it general that can accept string/integer
               database[:total_car_price] += data[selection]
               break
           else
               puts 'Incorrect selection!'
           end
       end
   end


   puts "Stock Price :: #{database[:stock_car_price]}"
   puts "Final Price :: #{database[:total_car_price]}"
   ```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: try `ruby -w <file>` to get a hint about where the error's occurring.

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You should parse you json like this:

```
json = {
   database: {
    total_car_price: 20000,
    stock_car_price: 20000,
    features: {
        rim: {
            '16' => 50,
            '15' => 30,
            '14' => 10
        },
        color: {
            'blue' => 0,
            'red'  => 0,
            'yellow' => 0
        },
        tint: {
            '100' => 80,
            '80' => 50,
            '50' => 0
        },
        seat: {
            'leather' => 500,
            'PVC' => 300
        }
    }
}
}

parsed_json = JSON.parse(json.to_json)

puts "Original price : #{parsed_json['database']['stock_car_price']}"
```

Here is the working sample:

[working code](https://repl.it/Dftb)